# External monitor is too yellow

Tags: display, screen, external-monitor, vga

When I bought a new screen (Philips 227e4l) and connected it with my laptop (HP Compaq 6520) via the VGA port, the size of screen is right (1920x1080), but the color is wrong (too much yellow).

How can I adjust the color of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a hardware problem. VGA cables carry the red, green, and blue color signals on separate wires. If the wire for the blue signal is damaged or poorly connected, the image on the monitor will appear yellow:

[image: additive color]

Things to try:

- Make sure both ends of the cable are firmly connected.
- Check for dirt in the connectors on the monitor and laptop.
- Watch the screen while wiggling the cable to check for internal breaks.
- Test with a different monitor, cable, and/or laptop to determine where the problem is occurring.